# Optimal permutations of kernel_initializer, activation function and optimizer for Regression

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am using the kernel_initializer='normal' and optimizer='adam' to find an optimum regression solution. I am getting close to 0.94 accuracy on training data. I would like to test a few other kernel_initializer, activation function and optimizer combinations but I am not sure kernel_initializer and activation function which works well for regression.  Please suggest

```
# create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='root_mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: Use `relu` or `leaky_relu` activations and if you want more accuracy use `SGD` optimiser but it'll be too slow

Answer (score 1):

Well, it might not be a good idea. You're after a fairly small margin in performance, and by "fishing" for good results you're essentially exploiting your validation as the training set, relying on small variations in the data to inform model design.

Few tips:

- Glorot initializer (default) is usually the best. However, the difference is really small, especially in such a tiny model.
- relu activation is helpful to fight vanishing gradients. With three layers in the model, you probably won't have it. Here it really depends on the nature of the data; even linear activation might make sense.
- for a regular regression (i.e. predicting a number, not a binary output(s)), you probably need to use linear regression on the output layer. It is the default one, but it's better to make it explicit.
- other optimizers might improve rate of conversion, but usually don't improve the performance. Adam sounds like a reasonable choice - sgd will do the same but slower, ftrl works the best on sparse data such as language input.